# How to store all the datafield that are selected in checkboxes on Flask web interface in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, flask

I created a Flask web page to show all the data fields in each row and the corresponding checkboxes. When I choose some data fields in checkboxes, I can see all the selected data fields on the command terminal. I would like to store all the selected data fields in a csv file so that it is more convenient for me to check the data. I was wondering how I can do that. I am new to Flask. Is there any specific function that I need to take a look at.

[Flask webpage description draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHFxT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

So, if you already have your values in a Flask view, then the rest is quite easy:

```
my_fields = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

csv_string = ','.join(my_fields)

with open('path-to-my-dump.csv', 'w') as f:
  f.write(csv_string)
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for the timely reply. Actually I do not have these values in a Flask view. All the data field were pulled from a server for each org Id I typed in. I have attached a draft below(I cannot share the screenshot of the original website due to privacy, sorry about that). All I want is to store the data fields that I checked under "Include" in a csv file.